# Can't handle touches simultaneously with WKWebView on iOS 13.4

Tags: swift, webkit, uigesturerecognizer, ios13.4

**Problem:**
Starting from iOS 13.4 WebKit intercepts gestures that previously were passed to the system and could be handled by `UIGestureRecognizer` simultaneously

**Demo project:**
I created `WKWebView` and added it to `UIViewController`'s view. I created also `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and added it to `UIViewControler`'s view as well.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pinchHandler))
        pinch.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)

        addWebView()
    }

    func addWebView() {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        self.webView = webView
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let localHtmlFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: localHtmlFile)
            webView?.load(request)
        }
    }

    @objc func pinchHandler() {
        debugPrint("PinchHandler called")
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
        if event.type == .touches {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I try to run sample html website added to main bundle:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .center {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              border: 3px solid #73AD21;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 100;
              overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function move(event) {
                console.log(event);
                event.preventDefault()
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body ontouchmove="move(event)" class="center">
            <p id="content">
                demo
            </p>
    </body
</html>
```

Website intercepts `touchmove` event and I'm cancelling it in `move(event)` function.

When I ran this code 10 times on iOS 13.0 Simulator, every time my handler worked. When I ran this code 10 times on iOS 13.4 Simulator, my pinch handler worked 4 times and didn't work 6 times.

Comment: Hi! I'm going through the same, did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: Still not workaround unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to use Javascript to detect the taps on the webview.
A running playground showing how to do it:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import WebKit

class TouchDetectionOnWKWebViewUsingJSDemoVC : UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
  override func loadView() {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 100, height: 200)), configuration: config)

    let jsEvent = "touchstart"
    let handlerName = "handler"
    let jsCode =
    """
    window.addEventListener('\(jsEvent)', function(e) {
      window.webkit.messageHandlers.\(handlerName).postMessage('\(jsEvent)')
    })
    """

    let jsScript = WKUserScript(source: jsCode, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(jsScript)
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: handlerName)

    let demoURL = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: demoURL))

    self.view = webView
  }

  func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message.body)
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = TouchDetectionOnWKWebViewUsingJSDemoVC()
```

In the example I show how to listen for `touchstart` event, but it can be any js event, e.g.: `touchend`, `touchmove`, `gesturestart`, `gestureend`, and others. We can even listen to scroll events (but I think is better to be the `webView.scrollView` delegate for that).

Comment: The problem is that there is an internal listener, that I have no access to, and it stops the responding chain by calling `event.preventDefault()`, so my listeners are not receiving the messages.