# iOS 13 UIPanGestureRecognizer selector not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, ios13, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm facing an issue whereby UIPanGestureRecognizer selector is not being called. UIPanGestureRecognizer is being tied to a WKWebView and its delegate to self (view controller).

UIPanGestureRecognizer delegate method is successfully called but not the selector method.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panningMethod:)];

[pan setDelegate:self];

[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:pan];


-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Any idea? I ran the code in earlier iOS version (e.g. iOS 12.2) and it is working perfectly fine

Comment: it is very likely that you got the impression of a working source code in older iOS version because maybe it was behaving as expected but the @selector function was never called to handle panning events.

Also your value is called mapView but you pan which view then? The WKWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WKWebView might be suppressing the gesture, found related discussion here: [Can't handle touches simultaneously with WKWebView on iOS 13.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208881/cant-handle-touches-simultaneously-with-wkwebview-on-ios-13-4)

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions/guesses related to the above.

1. Are you sure the delegate method is called for **that** pan gesture recognizer?
   Could you save your UIPanGestureRecognizer into the ivar and compare the addresses during the debug session? I mean the address of the ivar and of the gestures from your delegate method.
2. I can't say for sure why, but I got a similar problem once when I didn't implement other delegate method:
   `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch { return YES; }`
3. If nothing else works - this solution could help you:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/33819119/3008827

Hope this could help you. Sorry, if no.

Answer (score 0):

The WkWebView's loaded contents is responsible for the navigation inside, usually done with javascript or the default scrolling behaviour of webviews.
While `WKWebView` is a inherited class from `NSView` you can do all stuff with it that is possible with the super class.

so you can call

```
[self.mapview resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:NSZeroSize];
```

or/and

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
  return YES;
}
```

can be set.

You could also explicit define how interaction is handled.
The following example code was meant to be able to turn off a (bool)_cursor value to stop cursor interactions of a wkwebview.

```
#pragma mark - interaction interception

- (NSView*)hitTest:(NSPoint)point {
    if (_cursor) return [super hitTest:point];
    return nil;
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super keyDown:event];
}
- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super keyUp:event];
}

-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (_cursor) [super mouseMoved:event];
}
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (_cursor) [super mouseDown:event];
}
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (_cursor) [super mouseUp:event];
}
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (_cursor) [super mouseDragged:event];
}
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (_cursor) [super mouseEntered:event];
}
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (_cursor) [super mouseExited:event];
}
```

But there is a much simpler way.
You don't need `UIPanGestureRecognizer` when you implement the NSResponder protocol or use the corresponding methods for Views..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // do stuff 
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        // do stuff;
    }
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        // do stuff;
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

and last but not least..
just in case you missed the definition of your selector
your WKWebView needs the following **@implementation**

```
-(void)panningMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
}
```

and usually also the **@interface** definition

```
-(void)panningMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture;
```

and finally you do not need to call the explicit `-setDelegate` method after definition of a GestureRecogniser unless you meant to set the `-navigationDelegate` for the `WKWebView`.

Comment: and your `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`method is called and definied from/in where?